# SQL query count divided by a distinct count of same query

Tags: sql, oracle

Having some trouble with some SQL.

Take the following result for instance:

```
LOC_CODE     CHANNEL            
------------ -------------------- 
3ATEST-01    CHAN2            
3ATEST-01    CHAN3            
3ATEST-02    CHAN4
```

What I need to do is get a count of the above query, grouped by channel, but i want that count to be divided by the count that the "LOC_CODE" appears.

Example of the result I am after is:

```
 CHANNEL          COUNT
 ---------------- ----------
 CHAN2            0.5
 CHAN3            0.5
 CHAN4            1
```

Above explaination is that the CHAN2 appears next to "3ATEST-01", but that LOC_CODE of "3ATEST-01" appears twice, so the count should be divided by 2.

I know I can do this by basically duplicating the query with a distinct count, but the underlying query is quite complex and don't really want to harm performance.

Please let me know if you would like more information!

Comment: Question; is CHANNEL unique? If not, could you give an example of the result you'd like with a duplicated CHANNEL with another LOC_CODE?

Comment: HI. Channel is not unique (the first result may have channel in their numerous times). I would do a sum on the final outer query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select channel, 
       count(*) over (partition by channel, loc_code)
        / count(*) over (partition by loc_code) as count_ratio
from my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.CHANNEL, COUNT(*) / gr.TotalCount
FROM my_table t JOIN (
    SELECT LOC_CODE, COUNT(*) TotalCount
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY LOC_CODE
) gr USING(LOC_CODE)
GROUP BY t.LOC_CODE, t.CHANNEL
```

Create a index on `(LOC_CODE, CHANNEL)`

If are no duplicate channels, replace `COUNT(*) / gr.TotalCount` with `1 / gr.TotalCount` and remove the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Is there a different way that doesnt involve a separate subquery for the count? I don't think there is, but my query (my_table t in your example above) is quite a long query, and would like to avoid duplicating this just for a count.

Comment: @Lock: I don't think so. One of your requirements is to output results grouped by `Channel`. The other is to have calculations from a group by `Loc_Code`. If it is possible, it would probably be using analytic (window) functions, like Mark Bannister's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are still a bit unclear to me when it comes to duplicate CHANNELs, but this should work if you want grouping on both CHANNEL and LOC_CODE to sum up later;

```
SELECT L1.CHANNEL, 1/COUNT(L2.LOC_CODE) 
FROM Locations L1
LEFT JOIN Locations L2 ON L1.LOC_CODE = L2.LOC_CODE 
GROUP BY L1.CHANNEL, L1.LOC_CODE
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/41996/6).

Answer (score 0):

First, find a query that gets you the correct results. Then, see if it can be optimised. My guess is that it's hard to optimise as you require two different groupings, one per `Channel` and one pre `Loc_Code`.

I'm not even sure that this fits your description:

```
SELECT t.CHANNEL
     , COUNT(*) / SUM(grp.TotalCount)
FROM my_table t 
  JOIN 
      ( SELECT LOC_CODE
             , COUNT(*) TotalCount        --- or is it perhaps?:
                                          --- COUNT(DISTINCT CHANNEL)
        FROM my_table
        GROUP BY LOC_CODE
      ) grp 
     ON grp.LOC_CODE = t.LOC_CODE
GROUP BY t.CHANNEL
```